# Display first name instead of username

Tags: login, username

I have a plugin that outputs username after login, I want it to display first name instead.  Here is the code that does it.

```
        global $userdata,$user_identity;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        if ($userdata->ID>0) {
            // User is logged in
            echo '<div class="login">' . $before_widget . $before_title . "Welcome ".$user_identity . $after_title . '</div>';
            echo '
                <ul class="login-links">
                    <li><a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin/profile.php">Profile</a></li>

                </ul>
            ';
        } else {
        // User is NOT logged in!!!
                echo $before_widget . $before_title . '<div class="login">Welcome Guest, <a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin">Login</a></div>' . $after_title;
```

$user_identity is what outputs that username
I searched through wordpress forums and someone said I have to add `$current_user->first_name` to the code.
The question is, where and how do I add it?  I assume I would need to add it to this line `global $userdata,$user_identity;`  But how do I properly syntax that?
I tried doing this but getting syntax errors `global $userdata,$user_identity = $current_user->first_name;`

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change `global $userdata,$user_identity;` to `global $userdata, $current_user, $user_identity;`

Then change

```
echo '<div class="login">' . $before_widget . $before_title . "Welcome ".$user_identity . $after_title . '</div>';
```

to

```
echo '<div class="login">' . $before_widget . $before_title . "Welcome ".$current_user->user_firstname . $after_title . '</div>';
```

You can see all the info in the codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: +1. Seems we have practically identical answers, and minutes apart!

Comment: You are the man, too bad I can't vote you up because of having low reputation

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted answer. So that the system knows this question is answered. See the FAQ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

`$user_identity` uses the 'Display name publicly as' option on the user's profile page to decide what to display. So you can edit there.

Alternatively, to always display the first name, you can use the global `$current_user`: to get the first name:

```
$current_user->user_firstname
```

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)